# Как правильно в jetty выдавать статический контент?

Tags: java, java-ee, jetty

Я пишу приложение на servlet/jsp под jetty. Никак не могу понять, как правильно на страницу отображать картинки и т.д. Я сделал это при помощи отдельного сервлета, который привязал к url "img", а картинки запрашивал

"img?=someimg.png" , но в этом подходе мне не нравится следующее:
1) весь контент приходится хранить где-нибудь в директории jetty, как его читать из war-ника, когда я собираю и запускаю jetty из под idea я так и не понял...

2) кажется что это просто какой-то костыль...

```
String pathToImg = "/webapp/ROOT/images/";//этот путь до war-ника я тоже не понимаю
    BufferedInputStream streamImg = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathToImg));
    byte[] array = new byte[streamImg.available()];
    streamImg.read(array);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    bos.write(array);
```

Вообщем как это правильно сделать в jetty...?

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю пару слов про костыль `webapp/ROOT/images/`

`webapp/ROOT` - веб-приложение "по умолчанию" сервера приложений jetty, как я полагаю. Оно "по умолчанию" отображается на корневой контекст.
Этот ROOT ничего специального из себя не представляет и можете использовать его на своё усмотрение. Как вариант набросать туда тех же картинок, и ссылаться на них на страницах из других приложений. Но взамен такие приложения приобретают какую-то потустороннюю зависимость, что не есть хорошо. Лучше сделать из ROOT портал на другие установленные приложения.

Как уже заметили все веб-приложения на сервлетах жава доступны по url вида http://server/app_name. /app_name - и есть контекст приложения.
Адреса всех страниц и прочих веб-ресурсов приложения начинаются с контекста:
http://server/app_name/index.jsp, http://server/app_name/images/someimg.png

А этот ROOT доступен по адресу http://server/  Его контекст просто /

Название приложения, его контекст (и как следствие url) могут не совпадать. Даже можете назначить корень / своему приложение, а этот ROOT вообще отключить.

Но зачем надо было извращаться с этими `BufferedInputStream`-ами? Не понятно.
Картинка и в этом случае добавляется на страницу так же элементарно:

```
<img src="/images/someimg.png"/>
```

В Вашем примере картинка загружается из файла, пользуясь знанием где физически располагается этот файл. Полагаться на это знание ошибочно. Он может поменяться и работать перестанет. И как показано выше не надо это на самом деле.

Answer (score 3):

Ничего мудрить не надо. Просто поместите картинки туда же, где все ваши jsp. Там же делайте папки какие надо. Хотите картинки в папке images - сделайте папку images и поместите в неё картинку someimg.png
War-архив выглядит примерно так:

```
`--- /images
       `--- someimg.png
`--- index.jsp
`--- /WEB-INF
       `--- /classes
       `--- /lib
       `--- web.xml
```

Вся корневая папка кроме /WEB-INF доступна для клиента. JSP-страницы предварительно обрабатываются JSP-движком, остальное отдаётся как есть.

В JSP картинка вставляется обычным образом:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/someimg.png"/>
```

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}` будет заменяться на имя Вашего приложения. Если вдруг решите назвать его по-другому, то менять исходники JSP не надо будет.

Всё размещается в исходном прожекте.
Не знаю как это выглядит в idea, в Netbeans так:

```
/Прожект
  `--- /Веб-страницы
         `--- /WEB-INF
                `--- web.xml
         `--- /images
                `--- someimg.png
         `--- index.jsp
  `--- /Пакеты исходных кодов
```

Builder сделает war-архив как показан выше. В jetty ничего ни в каких директориях хранить не надо.

Если всё же есть нужда загрузить какой-то файл из War-архива в программу, то следует воспользоваться ресурсами. Например:

```
InputStream input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/images/someimg.png");
```

Comment: у меня css ссылается на картинки, так что ${pageContext.request.contextPath} он не переварит..

Comment: Тогда напишите /имя_вашего_приложения/images/someimg.png или относительный путь относительно (во как!) вашего css.

Comment: В JSF кстати такие подстановки работают, если css подключать на страницу с помощью специальных тегов JSF. Может и в JSP имеется что-то подобное.

Comment: я вот создал в /ROOT/ ссылку на папку проекта, который создаётся в /target/ в idea, чтобы было проще тестить, но jetty видит только первый уровень папки - в каталоги внутри ссылки он уже зайти не может - 404 , а в файловой системе и через консоль я нормально захожу..

Comment: С идеей не знаком. Что у находится в этой папке `target`?  Вообще приложение развёртывает на сервере под каким-то именем. Обычно это имя проекта. Если проект назвали myapp, то и на сервере оно будет myapp и ссылаться надо на myapp, пусть он хоть в десяти target-ах. В браузере в адресной строке что написано, когда проект запускаете? Ссылки делаются не с точки зрения расположения файлов на диске, а с точки зрения браузера

Comment: в target собирается /app_name/ который я могу спокойно положить в ROOT руками и он будет работать, а вот через ссылку почему-то нет

Comment: Так что ли получается? /webapps/ROOT/app_name? Если что - это не верно. Либо так должно быть - /webapps/app_name и адрес приложения http://server/app_name и это начало всех ссылок на его страницы, Либо содержимое app_name замещает содержимое ROOT, получается /webapps/ROOT и адрес его http://server/

Comment: вообщем ссылку на директорию с проектом в target переименовал в ROOT , теперь при старте сервера страницы jsp и картинки отдельными запросами загружаются, а вот на jsp из css они всёравно не вытягиваются ни 1 способом, я уже их везде накидал..

Comment: Как картинка в css прописана и где сам css находится? допустим в папке css (рядом с images), тогда `background: url(../images/someimg.png)` должен работать. `background: url(/images/someimg.png)` если приложение в /webapps/ROOT, `background: url(/app_name/images/someimg.png)` если в /webapps/app_name

Comment: css в папке css , img в папке images , /css/ и /images/ лежат в 1 директории , прописано так url(../images/pass-icon.png)

Comment: А css как прописан в JSP? `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/somecss.css" .../>`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
        <style>
            <%@include file='../css/login.css' %>
        </style> , Но стили то все отображаются нормально

Comment: Не знаю зачем таким образом вставлять css, дело ваше, но тогда url(../images/pass-icon.png) не будет работать. В url указывается относительный путь относительно файла css, но таким образом с include нет никакого файла css. Есть только допустим index.jsp. Для браузера login.css не существует! Тогда url надо записать по второму или третьему варианту. Или переделать внедрение css по-человечески через link

Comment: Так, стоп, почему так не будет работать и как правильно? Локально так работало, а как правильно надо я тут собственно и спрашиваю т.к. я чайник в вебе...У меня же все стили из css подгружаются нормально и всё корректно отображается в браузере..

Comment: Откройте в браузере просмотр кода страницы? Там нет никакого упоминания login.css. Верно? Но есть текст из этого файла. И он даже работает, но url он загрузить не может. url - это относительный путь. Допустим открыта `http://server/index.jsp`, `url (../images/img.png)` Две точки `..` указывают браузеру подняться вверх относительно текущего url, но он и так в самом корне сервера, дальше хода нет. Если открыта `http://server/app_name/index.jsp`, то от app_name подымется до корня и спустится в images. Вот такой адрес будет загружать `http://server/images/img.png`

Comment: Вообщем кажется заработало так: вызываю из css вот так url(../images/user-icon.png) , а строки с include я закомментировал, большое спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/somecss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>` так должно быть и всё.